# MS BUILD ERROR Command failed with exit code 1, Cordova Visual Studio 2017

Tags: cordova, uwp, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova

I am building an App with cordova in Visual Studio 2017. 
So far I've tested it on Android only and it is almost ready.
I wanted to start testing on Windows 10 mobile but I've fallen into this error when compiling the project for Windows (any platform: arm, x64, x86, all get me to the same error)

This is the error I get:

```
------ Building platform: windows
------ Build configuration options:  --debug -- --win --archs x86

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
[VSTAC_VERBOSE]No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
[VSTAC_VERBOSE]Reading build config file: C:\Users\lucaz\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Notebet\Notebet\build.json
[VSTAC_VERBOSE]Running command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" -version -nologo
[VSTAC_VERBOSE]Command finished with error code 0: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe -version,-nologo
Building project: C:\Users\lucaz\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Notebet\Notebet\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
    Configuration : debug
    Platform      : x86
[VSTAC_VERBOSE]Running command: C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows" /s /v InstallationFolder /reg:32
[VSTAC_VERBOSE]Command finished with error code 0: C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe query,HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows,/s,/v,InstallationFolder,/reg:32
[VSTAC_VERBOSE]Running command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" "C:\Users\lucaz\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Notebet\Notebet\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj" /clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal /nologo /p:Configuration=debug /p:Platform=x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\JavaScript\Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.UAP.targets(82,3): error : "10.0.15063.0" non � un valore supportato per TargetPlatformVersion. Modificarlo nella pagina delle propriet� del progetto. [C:\Users\lucaz\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Notebet\Notebet\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
[VSTAC_VERBOSE]Command finished with error code 1: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe C:\Users\lucaz\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Notebet\Notebet\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj,/clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal,/nologo,/p:Configuration=debug,/p:Platform=x86
1>    MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1
1>  Done executing task "VsTac" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "BuildMDA" in project "Notebet.jsproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Done building project "Notebet.jsproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Project Performance Summary:
1>     3983 ms  C:\Users\lucaz\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Notebet\Notebet\Notebet.jsproj   1 calls
1>
1>Target Performance Summary:
1>        0 ms  BuildOnlySettings                          1 calls
1>        0 ms  AfterBuild                                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  BeforeBuild                                1 calls
1>        0 ms  CheckForIPACancel                          1 calls
1>        0 ms  CoreBuild                                  1 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform   1 calls
1>        0 ms  CompileTypeScript                          1 calls
1>        3 ms  PreComputeCompileTypeScript                1 calls
1>      730 ms  EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion   1 calls
1>     3244 ms  BuildMDA                                   1 calls
1>
1>Task Performance Summary:
1>        0 ms  Message                                    2 calls
1>        4 ms  VsTsc                                      2 calls
1>        8 ms  CreateBuildInfoMetadata                    1 calls
1>      729 ms  MdaVerifySetup                             1 calls
1>     3235 ms  VsTac                                      1 calls
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

When it says: "error : "10.0.15063.0" non � un valore supportato per TargetPlatformVersion. Modificarlo nella pagina delle propriet� del progetto. "
It is italian even though I have visual studio in English (no idea why that is), it means : "error : "10.0.15063.0" value not supported for TargetPlatformVersion. Change it in the propety page of the project."

So far I checked that document and changed the value from 10.0.10240.0 to 10.0.15063.0 as it is the version of the W10 sdk i have on my pc, thinking that that might have been the problem.

Checking on my visual studio installer it says I have the Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0) for UWP

It didn't work and as googling I have found people having problems compiling cordova projects for windows but I didnt find anyone with my error.

Thanks for any advice, I hope I've provided enough informations, in case you need more I'll provide them as fast as possible.

Comment: Could you please try it with an empty blank project?

Comment: Just did it, I got the same error but with "10.0.10240.0" since I haven't changed it.

Comment: Blank project builds fine... I have the same error